# Quartz.NET after web hosting

Tags: quartz.net

I have an ASP.NET application and a job scheduled using Quartz.NET that runs once every day. The job execution is nothing but a method call (Execute method to be specific) in one of the classes that implements IJob interface.
If I host this web application on GoDaddy's grid hosting (they call it a cloud) where we dont have access to the physical server, would this job still run?

Comment: Are you referring to Cloud Servers or 4GH shared hosting?

Comment: I was unable to find a definitive answer in Quartz NET documentation on if it will run on a clustered server environment.  Also, 4GH hosting is set to Medium Trust which looks like it may cause issues.

Comment: Would it work in cloud servers?

Comment: Cloud servers would be able to run at any trust level you want so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Quart.Net has some dependencies to 3rd party libraries (common logging) that do not let it run under medium trust. So, if you can host Quartz.Net somewhere it can run under full trust, you should be ok, otherwise, you'll need to recompile Quartz.Net without the dependency to common logging.